# How to center li that is table

Tags: html, css

I have my sidebar code:
http://jsfiddle.net/48Wse/

My li's are currently displayed as `tables`. Now, I would like to center content inside `li` so that left and right paddings would always be the same. `Text-align: center` does most of the job but it's not correct.

Image what I want:
[image]

Comment: Btw: why are you using display table and table-cell? Doesn't seem any different with block elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your clocks seems to not have a fluid width, you could use :

```
li {
    display: block; /* not necessary, just remove table */
    ...

    .data {
        display: block; /* not necessary, just remove inline-block/table-cell */
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 200px;
        ...
    }
}
```

This will center your clocks, **and keep the label left-aligned** :

[image]

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/48Wse/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

your .data has text-align: left .. should be center.

```
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48Wse/2/

Comment: The label isn't supposed to be centered as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
li * {
    text-align:center;
}
```

in your css.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/48Wse/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Set  `text-align:center;` on the li

Set `display:inline-block;` on the .data div

Set `text-align:left` on the .title

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/48Wse/5/)**

PS: There's no need to set a width on the data div